# How to redirect to home page according to a specific page custom fields value and user name

Tags: custom-field, redirect, wp-redirect

I have some pages where specific users only should have access to those specific pages.

So I created a custom field to assign the user name to the specific page.
Custom fields : http://take.ms/tCCWQ

if the current username and the custom field values are NOT same then the page should be redirected to some other pages.

I put this page in my footer.php

```
if( is_page() ) { // run only if it is a page
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $getClient = get_post_meta($postid, 'clientName', true);

    $clientName = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clientName', true ); 
    if  (!empty( $clientName )) { // run only if the specific custom field has value
            if ($getClient !== $current_user){ // if the current user and the custom feilds vlaues are NOT same
                echo '<br/>this page is NOT assigned for you';
                header("Location: https://www.google.com"); /* if not same then Redirect */
                exit();
            }
        }
}
```

I see this message in the footer only if I am in a page where the page has this custom field value.
So the logic works perfectly but the issue is redirection does not work.
If the current user name and the custom field are **not** same then it should be redirected to another page.

Why it does not work? how can I fix this?

It's fine if I can use this in `login_redirect` filter or using `wp_redirect($url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the headers have been sent (output has been written to the screen) you can not use `wp_redirect()` try placing your code in the `header.php` before any output and see if that works well enough.

If not you will have to hook into `'send_headers'`, `'template_redirect'`, or `'init'` and check the values and redirect before any output.